# Listbox with linq and multiple selection

Tags: c#, linq, listbox

Got 2 listboxes: Patients and Sessions.
Need to display filtered (with linq query) info in the second one, based on multiple selection in the first one.

Commented string works but allows only one item to be selected in the first listbox.

I definitely know that it successfully gathers Patients to List variable but when I use Contains the second listbox is empty.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext dbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    List<string> selectedItems = (from object o in listBox1.SelectedItems select listBox1.GetItemText(o)).ToList();
    listBox2.DataSource = dbContext.Sessions
    //.Where(pID => pID.PatientID == listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedValue))
      .Where(pID => selectedItems.Contains(pID.PatientID));
    listBox2.DisplayMember = "Start";
    listBox2.ValueMember = "SessionID";
}
```

Session and dbContext class definitions:

```
public partial class Session : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    ...
    public int SessionID
        {
        ...
        }
    public string PatientID
        {
        ...
        }
    }

public partial class DataClasses1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    {
    ...
    public System.Data.Linq.Table<Session> Sessions
        {
        ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: what your exception?

Comment: No exceptions, It just loads emply listBox2.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what type of element you are having in your listbox1. I assumed the type is named `Session`:

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext dbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        List<string> selectedItems = (from object o in listBox1.SelectedItems select listBox1.GetItemText(o)).ToList();
        listBox2.DataSource = dbContext.Sessions
            .Where(pID => listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<Session>().Select(x => x.PatientID).Contains(pID.PatientID));
        listBox2.DisplayMember = "Start";
        listBox2.ValueMember = "SessionID";
    }
```

Comment: Still nothing is displayed in listBox2 :(

Comment: what type is `dbContext.Sessions` and `PatientID` ? Can you post more code in your question?

Comment: Done. Is that ok? I'm a newbie, sorry.

Comment: if you define a breakpoint, what is stroed in `List<string> selectedItems` and `dbContext.Sessions`. Are there any elements?

Comment: `List<string> selectedItems` has proper `<string>` items.

`dbContext.Sessions` has `{Table(Session)}`, `Context {testproj.DataClasses1DataContext}`

Comment: Found something. `listBox2.DataSource` has no items in `Results view`. It's kinda obvious but still.